# Can I theoritcally climb The Mount Erciyes in the summer?

Tags: climbing, mountaineering, free-solo-climbing

I recently wanted to climb that mountain because I literally love pushing myself and it looks fun.

**Information about me**

- I am a 15.9 year old male teen (14-12-02)
- I live in İzmir Karşıyaka (30 meters above sea level (MASL)
- The walking distance to my school is 1.9 Kilometers and I always go there and come from there on foot  with my somewhat heavy backpack. (I have always gone to the school on foot in my life)
- Iron deficiency anemia (not very strong but I don't drink tea so I think its not a big problem also I don't use anemia pills anyway)
- I have not even climbed a single gravel pile in my life

**The Field**

- I will go to the Kayseri by bus on The Summer
- Before climbing Erciyes I will stay at the local village Yahyalı a few days (1330 MASL) for making my body adjust itself

**The Plan**

- Grab the leather and fur coat (sheep) and dress thick (also not forget the feet and the legs) and wear some gloves and some good boots
- Tuck in the layered clothes for making an air seal
- Have Nokia N8 as an mirroeles compact camera (or an C1300D DSLR) and the Vibe P1 Turbo for the altimer ler (climb recorder)
- a small backpack with water and food
- Climb to the summit of The Erciyes **Alone** (3917 MASL)

**Possible Problems\Outcomes**

- I get frostbite...
- My parents won't let me do it
- The heavy, sheep  leather and fur coat of my grandpa eats  all my energy
- I literally slip/fall
- Phone literally freezes
- I Suffocate

**Questions**

- How much water should I bring?
- what should be the weight of my backpack plus the coat? (I may get an full sized tripod too)
- will I make it without dying or getting parts of my body amputated or permanent organ damage ?
- does the standard rate of tempeture decrease of 1 degrees celcius every 200 meters hold up there?
- Will my phones freeze?
- Is my plan decent?

Comment: I vote to reopen this question because there is enough information given to answer it - and I think it is an interesting question.
That being said I have to emphasise that I agree with @Loren Pechtel below - this is *not* a climb for a novice and the proposed plan is, frankly, highly dangerous.

Comment: The only thing that makes me question this question here is there are a whole bunch of sub-questions which could be split.

Comment: Totally agree with @Aravona: Please split this question up focusing on one aspect at a time. This is not to hackle you, but to ensure you will get the best answers possible to all your questions.

Comment: I voted to reopen because the question is actually very narrow; it is not at all broad. The core of the question is: Can a 16 year old admittedly utterly without experience and not properly equipped solo climb a 12,800 foot mountain without a decent trail and that culminates with technical climbing? All the detail that makes the question look "too broad" is extraneous to the core of the question.  Eventually, with experience, the OP may well climb this mountain, but not now, and probably not next summer, and we would do him and readers a great disservice not to take this question seriously.

Comment: (continued) This OP asked an important question and splitting the Q would detract from the Q because the split-offs, for example, about suffocation, or about temperature drop with altitude, do not address the core of the question: is this climb feasible for me? The logical followup question is in the comments, not in the question itself: "What do I need to know, and how do I gain the knowledge and experience to make this climb feasible?"

Comment: I think trying to get to the heart of and answer this question is specifically useful to this individual and broadly useful to many with similar questions (in other words a good use of Stack Exchange).

Comment: You can take a look at the [photo album](https://www.facebook.com/media/set/?set=a.1443342661040.41718.1757312418&l=faad6e8d17&type=1) from Rob Woodall. He is a very serious mountaineer with an impressive pedigree and if he turned back from the summit pinnacle, it's for a good reason. Looking at the picture of the chimney to the summit, it looks real scary how bad the rock seems to be.

Comment: @GabrielC. The "triangle" top looks like a knife actually. Would it be logical to walk over it?

Comment: Join your equivalent of Scouts/ out door youth group. Bug the leaders to take you hiking.

Comment: @ldgorman I always liked being a lone wolf (3ven though I dont think I am very competent person) that will die because of his faults. But still thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From what I have read, I would say the part of your plan to

> Climb to the summit of The Erciyes Alone (3917 MASL)

is a no go with your experience and gear.

Assuming this [route description](http://www.goereme.net/erciyes.html) is accurate the climb/hike starts at 2750m after a drive and a couple of chair lifts.

[image]

Your gear should be fine to get you there in the summer. It is then a 2.5 hour hike to PARMAK KAYA at 3700m. There is apparently a visible path with a moderate grade. From there you would have a nice view of the summits. Your gear would not be too much of a problem, but lack of experience and age would worry me. You would probably want to go with someone else, preferable someone with more experience.

From PARMAK KAYA to HÖRGÜC KAYA 3820m there are a number of obstacles requiring navigating a steep snow field and loose gravel slopes with constant danger of rock fall. This is the first summit. You might be able to make it there. As long as you can keep moving your cloths will be plenty warm. You do not mention anything about footwear, but you are probably going to need heavy boots to be able to kick steps and you may want/need an ice axe for balance. Given your experience this is probably a no go. With someone how knows what they are doing and reasonable boots, you could probably do this. That said, it is a serious climb and there could be many reasons that would force you to turn back.

To get to the summit 3917, there is a section of real rock climbing on what appears to be loose rock with some serious potential for a slip to result in a very big fall. Note the ice axes, helmets, and clothing for comparison purposes.

[image]

Some of the climb might be protected by a rope ladder, but from the descriptions I have seen, not all of it is.

[image]

The descent is the same as the ascent, so you need to be able to go both up and down. There is no way I would take an inexperienced person on that route without having first hand knowledge of the climb and descent.

In summary, the hike to PARMAK KAYA sounds and looks awesome. I would suggest trying to find someone with a little more experience and giving that a shot. You should be able to get lots of photos and stoke your desire to do more climbing.

Comment: Chair lifts? Since I'd like an "purist" approach I would mount them. Still how difficult it becomes if I climb from the bottom to the top without help of any vehicles?

Comment: @JonathanIrons, extremely difficult if you do not have much more experience than you have now.

Comment: @JonathanIrons I am not sure how you are defining the bottom, but it does not really matter. Everything up to the top of the chair lifts is straightforward hiking on cleared, but steep, terrain. The problem becomes making the day very long.

Answer (score 15):

Categorically, no.

1)  As ab2 said, you need experience.  You need to learn how much you can do (note that hiking endurance isn't very related to how one performs in sports--my nephew is 10 years younger than I am, plays multiple sports frequently but I, who have never played sports, can go much farther than he can) and how you handle altitude.  I routinely hike in areas 2,400m to 3,000m above sea level, we live 800m above sea level.  I see plenty of people up there who can't handle the altitude.

2)  What ab2 missed is the nature of the climb itself.  His advice would be appropriate if it were simply a hike on a reasonable trail.  However, that is not the case--you are climbing on **loose** volcanic rock.  This is a skill you obviously do not have and even with experience this isn't exactly the safest thing to be doing.  (Personally, this alone would make me reject it on safety reasons.)

3)  Even worse than the loose rock is that you can't reach the summit without mountaineering skills and equipment, something else you obviously do not possess.

4)  Your proposed clothing is unsuitable.  I say this without needing to know anything about how warm your coat is because no possible coat is acceptable.  The problem is the temperature will be changing as you go up, and as the day progresses, for this much of an ascent you must have multiple layers of clothing so you can add or remove as you go.

As for the hazards you mention:

Keeping your phone from freezing is simple enough--carry it inside a warm layer of clothing.  I've been hailed on, my phone in my shirt pocket didn't care.  However, unless it's in airplane mode (which means no GPS) you're very likely to run your battery out.

Slip/fall--given what you describe vs what you're facing I would say the only question is how badly you fall.

Suffocate--no danger of that, but if you pushed on despite altitude sickness symptoms you're getting into the range where it could be life threatening.

Frostbite--I'd be more worried about not making it down in time and getting stuck overnight and getting hypothermia.

Edit:  Since you still don't seem to realize what you're facing:  While I haven't found any pictures of what the mountaintop itself is like I have found multiple people who have rated it as class IV.  Thus I grabbed an image of a class IV route--this is simply the first hit from Google, not selected to be a hard example:

[image: Class IV path]

Comment: Well P1 has 5000 Mah battery so I guess it will make it with an powerbank feeding it (I didnt bought one yet).
There are nearby mountains like Mount sipylus and Yamanlar. Would tem be an decent test for me ? (The hardest part will be climbing a mountan with lots of organic obstacles.
 So where should I start when I go there ? there are lot more hills near my commodition (I may start by directly climbing an volcanic one if it exists).
 One more thing. I will climb that mountain in the middle of summer no matter what.

Comment: @JonathanIrons Did you not read the part about needing mountaineering equipment and skills?  If injury doesn't take you out on the way up the final ascent will most likely result in dying in a fall.  Note that ab2 seems to have deleted his answer because he didn't actually look up the mountain and realize it's no place for a novice.  And simply finding another volcanic peak for practice isn't nearly enough.

Comment: so where should I start?

Comment: Start by walking up the mountain in the lower regions, going up a bit more each time or walk other hills. Once you are confident you can walk up the side of the mountain (or already before that time) find a group that does mountain climbing, or if not available, bouldering or other kinds of climbing and train with them, to learn the basics and train your muscles, and follow their advice to advance to the mountain climbing you need.

Comment: @Willeke And check what the route is like, not merely the distance.

Comment: *'so where should I start'* The key thing you need are the skills to evaluate what you are getting into, and what's within your grasp. Start by doing that. You can often find local mountaineering and hiking groups that teach those skills at low cost. The [Turkish Mountaineering Federation](http://en.tdf.gov.tr) might be a place to start.

Comment: In addition, you may easily get lost and find yourself on terrain that looks much worse than that in the picture (done IV is the grade of the actual route), remain stuck with no way to get either up or down, and hope someone finds you before you've frozen to death.